REDUCE with conditional VSTACK inside LAMBDA. Is it possible?
I'm trying to build a VSTACK from a dynamic range using REDUCE.
What I'm getting:

What I want (note ignored XX value)

Essentially, the question is how to use conditional HSTACK inside LAMBDA inside REDUCE. Here I want to ignore cells with "XX" as a value, and create a HSTACK'd dynamic spill.
I know I could just use FILTER but this is just a simple example, where I often want to do more complex conditional edits inside a reduce depending on the cell value and then HSTACK the results (or ignore).
I don't understand what the #N/A values are due to.
HSTACK works without the conditional i.e this works (append "%" and HSTACK):


You've got your arguments swapped in the IF - it should be: =REDUCE("",A1:A6,LAMBDA(init,cell,IF(cell="XX",init,HSTACK(init,cell)))) and you'll want to wrap that in DROP to get rid of the first blank. For future reference, posting the formula as a picture doesn't really help us to help you. ;)

Thanks Rory. Good pickup, I think this is the crux of it.

Practicing With the REDUCE Function

I guess Rory said it all in your comments.
I like to put the inputs in the first row so the formula is 'LAMBDA-ready' (ready to be converted to a LAMBDA function in the Name Manager).
When using REDUCE, often you will use "" as the first argument, and in simple requirements like yours, a column (or a row) as the 2nd argument. The "" will yield a dummy first result and should be removed with DROP.
Inside the LAMBDA, I use rr and r for a column since I'm looping through rows (or cc and c for a row since I'm looping through columns).
It is important to understand that rr represents the current stacked result while r represents the value in the current row.
If you don't want to stack, keep the result (rr) as is (rewrite rr)— otherwise, stack rr and r as required.

=LET(data,A1:A6,exclude,"XX",suffix,"%",
    DROP(REDUCE("",data,LAMBDA(rr,r,
        IF(r=exclude,rr,HSTACK(rr,r&suffix)))),,1))


LAMBDA-Ready

In this particular case, I will replace LET with LAMBDA and remove all arguments in the first row:
=LAMBDA(data,exclude,suffix,
     DROP(REDUCE("",data,LAMBDA(rr,r,
         IF(r=exclude,rr,HSTACK(rr,r&suffix)))),,1))


Then I'll use this formula in the Name Manager and create a name e.g. StackColumnH to be able to use this LAMBDA function anywhere in the workbook:
=StackColumnH(A1:A6,"XX","&")



More Efficient Ways to Meet the Requirement (Hardly Relevant)
MS365
=LET(data,A1:A6,exclude,"XX",suffix,"%",
    TOROW(IFS(data<>exclude,data&suffix),2))

Excel 2021
=LET(data,A1:A6,exclude,"XX",suffix,"%",
    TRANSPOSE(FILTER(data&suffix,data<>exclude)))


I like the 'Hardly Relevant' bits. +1

Use FILTER() and TOROW(). Try-
=TOROW(FILTER(A1:A100,(A1:A100<>"XX")*(A1:A100<>""))&"%")



To work with REDUCE() you will need a IF() function. =REDUCE("",A1:A6,LAMBDA(init,cll,HSTACK(init,IF(cll="XX","",cll&"%")))).

With REDUCE it stacks empty cell between D and E while OP's wanted result (second picture) has none so it still needs to be filtered out

@user11222393 You are right. Just need to filter out or ignore empty results.

I didn't get it to work with REDUCE; but I used MAP with FILTER instead, maybe that's also enough for your future projects:
=FILTER(MAP(A1:A7;LAMBDA(a;IF(a="xx";"";a)));A1:A7<>"xx")



Isn't that doing the same work twice? Why not just =FILTER(A1:A7,A1:A7<>"XX")

@Rory basically yes, but OP wanted something else than just FILTER, I'm not sure what their intention is in the future.

Fair enough, but it would be more usual to use MAP for the criteria, I would have said.
